# how to code a WP plugin to delivery a file to client through browser

Tags: php, wordpress, limit

HI I need To code a plugin for WP TO DO the:

I have some files ( 4GB or 8GB ) to sell and no limit for downlaod after payment
but I need to add a free link but limited speed
look
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFsM8.png)
the orginal link:
https://dl.globalsystemformobile.com/data/get/exe/remote/Xiaomi_Unbricker_v1.exe
and limited link:

```
https://globalsystemformobile.com/filedownload?filedownload=19902204
```

ok ???
its work and speed will limit ( using Dlay(500) function )
but in my host the plugin will gonna add some data in frist line of data so no any file gonna work
its the problem

in other host and in clean wordpress installation its work nice

Comment: I’m not clear on your problem. Is it that everyone should be able to download these files, but you want to limit non-paying users in some fashion? Also, I think you are saying that on one server some data is being added before the file’s payload? Am I correct in my understanding?